# next js error build : next build not working because error css

Tags: next.js

Hello I try to build my project but it gives me errors.I am being told precisely about a webpack error

adgroupe@0.1.0 build C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe

> next build

info  - Checking validity of types
info  - Creating an optimized production build
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\static\css\93f817412a0f74ff.css:801:13: Unknown word
at makeWebpackError (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:41664:9)
at C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:25354:12
at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:140346:10), :34:1)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
-- inner error --
CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\static\css\93f817412a0f74ff.css:801:13: Unknown word
at Input.error (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:148:16)
at ScssParser.unknownWord (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:522:22)
at ScssParser.other (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
at ScssParser.parse (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
at scssParse (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:322)
at new LazyResult (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:133:16)
at Processor.process (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:28:14)
at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\css-minimizer-plugin.js:43:12)
at C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\css-minimizer-plugin.js:77:55
at runMicrotasks ()
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\static\css\93f817412a0f74ff.css:801:13: Unknown word
at Input.error (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\input.js:148:16)
at ScssParser.unknownWord (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:522:22)
at ScssParser.other (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:149:12)
at ScssParser.parse (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\parser.js:59:16)
at scssParse (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:322)
at new LazyResult (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:133:16)
at Processor.process (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\lib\processor.js:28:14)
at CssMinimizerPlugin.optimizeAsset (C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\css-minimizer-plugin.js:43:12)
at C:\Users\alain\Documents\PROJECTS\ADGROUPE\adgroupe\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\css-minimizer-plugin.js:77:55
at runMicrotasks ()

> Build failed because of webpack errors
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! adgroupe@0.1.0 build: `next build`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the adgroupe@0.1.0 build script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-04-03T09_05_40_524Z-debug.log

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.